# mysql not exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

my emp table is like this

```
+------+------------+
| emp  | emp_status |
+------+------------+
| 001  | w          |
| 002  | nw         |
| 003  | w          |
| 004  | w          |
+------+------------+
```

and salary table is

```
+------+------------+
| emp  | month      |
+------+------------+
| 001  | Dec2013    |
| 002  | Dec2013    |
| 003  | Dec2013    |
| 004  | Dec2013    |
| 001  | Jan2014    |
| 002  | Jan2014    |
| 003  | Jan2014    |
| 004  | Jan2014    |
| 001  | Feb2014    |
| 004  | Feb2014    |
+------+------------+
```

so for the month of Feb2014 i want to get the emp who wasn't paid

```
+------+------------+
| emp  | emp_status |
+------+------------+
| 003  | w          |
+------+------------+
```

i tried with

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT emp FROM salary where month_sal ='Feb2014')
```

and i want to use emp_status(with 'w') aswell... any hint..

Comment: Look at MySQL `JOIN`. This will allow you to query multiple tables from one SQL query statement.

Comment: it's weird that the month is saved as string. Use `DATE` datatype works better.

Comment: @raptor will change... thanx

Comment: @BigChris tried with JOIN first then only, i shifted to not exist...

Comment: @Raptor While I agree it IS weird, your alternative won't necessarily work better... at least not until the OP needs to start using range queries!

Comment: @Strawberry that's why side notes are posted as comments instead of answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm quietly lamenting the death of the outer join. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to connect the `where` clause in the `EXISTS` to the outer query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM salary 
    where salary.month_sal ='Feb2014'
    AND salary.emp=emp.emp
)
AND emp.emp_status='w'
```

What you were starting to write looks like a `IN`. You can also do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp 
WHERE NOT emp.emp IN 
(
    SELECT salary.emp 
    FROM salary 
    where salary.month_sal ='Feb2014'
)
AND emp.emp_status='w'
```

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous, because if one salary.emp is NULL, no rows at all will be returned. To always use NOT EXISTS instead, is my advice.

Comment: @jarlh : I would agree. I am just showing the OP diffrent possiblility to write the query

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp
WHERE emp_status = 'w'
  AND emp NOT IN (SELECT emp FROM emp WHERE month_sal ='Feb2014')
```

It looks slightly odd having a field name the same as the table name, but hopefully that's correct.